# Blank website after applying patches. What can i have done wrong?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, patches

I applied patches 5344 and 5994 though terminal (mac) and i got the response that they were successfully applied.

Than i went to my sites admin panel and i cleared all caches. After that the site was a blank page.

What could i have done wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No i haven't been able to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should check your apache error log.  Might be a permissions issue.

Comment: strange because another site applied it without this issue... same server... any idea what i should be looking for?

Comment: You should be looking for php syntax errors.  If they exist, they can stop blocks from rendering, resulting in blank pages.  And since you just applied a patch, I was thinking it was less likely to be a code issue and more likely to be permissions so I'd look for it saying that it can't find or include certain files.